# How to restart network Interfaces on virtual machine instead of complete machine reboot/reset using pyvmomi API

Tags: vmware, pyvmomi, netmon

I am working on a application which cloned virtual machines from a running machine on a specific event in **poweredon** state. The machines later communicate each other based on event and I have to fetch out (sniff) the network packets through [netmon](https://logrhythm.com/products/logrhythm-netmon/) virtual machine which is routed between them but I can't do so directly, I have to reboot the guest on virtual machines manually and then I can access the network reports.

I also tried to rebootguest of vm using [pyvmomi](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi) but the machine guest will take too much time to be in initial state after boot, I also do poll in loop to check virtual machine guest tool status and network status as well but nothing work, I got the empty network reports.

I did some research and found this is the right place to post this question, please let me know I am in wrong direction.